# How to provide access (Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-security

How can you put the right, so that only the admin can go to the JSP pages using his username and password. Suppose a page (allStudents.jsp) is available only to the admin, for this he must enter his username and password

How can you put the right, so that only the admin can go to the JSP pages using his username and password. Suppose a page (allStudents.jsp) is available only to the admin, for this he must enter his username and password

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Order(1)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Component
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("1234"))
          .authorities("ROLE_ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/securityNone").permitAll() //??????
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
          .httpBasic()
          .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);

        http.addFilterAfter(new CustomFilter(),
          BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5N5D.png)

I am Changed code please view this code

```
@Order(1)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Component
public class СostumWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("1234"))
          .authorities("ROLE_ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/allStudents").hasRole("ADMIN");
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
          .httpBasic()
          .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);

        http.addFilterAfter(new CustomFilter(),
          BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your endpoint for calling allStudents.jsp? can you post your controller where you call allStudents.jsp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Full Page Authorization Example**

> With expressions enabled for the http element, an URL pattern can be
>   secured as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/allStudents").hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN"); // assuming this is your endpoint/controller for allStudents.jsp page
    }
}
```

**Method Level Authorization Example – @PreAuthorize**

> Security Expressions can be used to secure business functionality at
>   the method level as well, by using annotations.
>
> The annotations @PreAuthorize and @PostAuthorize (as well as
>   @PreFilter and @PostFilter) support Spring Expression Language (SpEL)
>   and provide expression-based access control.
>
> First, in order to use method level security, we need to enable this
>   in the security configuration using @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   ...
}
```

> Then, we can secure methods using the Spring @PreAuthorize annotation:

```
@Service
public class FooService {
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public List<Foo> findAll() { ... }
    ...
}
```

---

For more in depth explanation for this examples, you can refer to this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-expressions-basic)

Comment: change the `.hasRole("ADMIN")` to `.hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")` because that is the role that you set in your inmemory authentication user.